# Auto number Generated in Php ajax is not Working

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to do the auto generated ID in php ajax. but it is not working.

What i tried so far, is in the following code:

I don't know what was the error. I went through the console, Ii couldn't find any errors...

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "layhospital";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("connection failed" . $conn->connect_error);
}
$query = "select MAX(doctorno) from doctor";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query))
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $count = $row['doctorno'];
    if ($count == "")
    {
        $doctor_ID = "CUS0";
    }
    else
    {
        $doctor_ID = substr($count, 3);
        $doctor_ID = intval($doctor_ID);
        $doctor_ID =    ("CUS" . ($doctor_ID + 1));
    }
    echo json_encode($doctor_ID);

}
?>
```

**jQuery code**

```
 function getAutoid()
    {
        $('#dno').empty();

        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : 'php/Doctor/autoid.php',
            dataType : "JSON",
            success : function (data)
            {
                $("#dno").val(data);
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry sir. i edited the question above thanks

Comment: What is the output of the AJAX Call in the Console. Also please show how your "dno" Element is defined.

Comment: try to print `data` in success function of ajax . i,e : `alert(data);` and check what does it have.